# SQL code to count only duplicates where all instances of the duplicate are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large data set with duplicate reference numbers (reference duplications range from 0 to 37 times). I want to count the number of references only where all instances are null in two columns. So using the table below, the code should return 1 because only Reference Code 3 has all null values, and the duplicates should only be counted once.

I would be grateful for any help.

[image: Table showing test data]

Comment: @Larnu count all the distinct reference code values where that code does not have a single row where A or B is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This involves two steps: (1) isolate all the distinct pairs of values that only have null; (2) count each one once. One way to express this in a query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT refnum FROM #ref 
    GROUP BY refnum
    HAVING MIN(colA) IS NULL 
    AND MIN(colB) IS NULL;
) AS x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation to get the codes:

```
select code
from t
group by code
having max(a) is null and max(b) is null;
```

If you want the count, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select code
      from t
      group by code
      having max(a) is null and max(b) is null
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  refcode
from referencecodes
group by refcode
having sum(case when (a is null and b is null) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

The above will return the codes with only `null` values in `a` and `b`.
If you want the number of codes:

```
select count(r.refcode) from (
    select 
      refcode
    from referencecodes
    group by refcode
    having sum(case when (a is null and b is null) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
) r
```

Or with EXISTS:

```
select 
  count(distinct r.refcode)
from referencecodes r
where not exists (
  select 1 from referencecodes
  where (refcode = r.refcode) and (a is not null or b is not null)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f47d102ca1b4ab618b8be9743464176)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful replies guys. I can confirm the code in the first post works, and the code in the subquery in the second post. Forpas: I haven't tried your code but I have saved your code and the demo so I can refer back to it :)